# How to SELECT based on grouped SUM that is compared to the AVG of that grouped SUM

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench, mysql-error-1111

I have a table consists of films, categories and prices.
Now I want to select only categories with total price (sum of all the price per film under that category) that is higher than the average of those categories' total prices.
I have been able to find the average of the total prices (thanks to this web) but can't combine it together.
Here are the queries:

```
-- Return the average sums of the price per category
SELECT AVG(sum_price)
FROM 
(
SELECT category, sum(price) AS sum_price
FROM film_list
GROUP BY category
) AS inner_query;

-- Return category and its total price
SELECT category, SUM(price)
FROM film_list
GROUP BY category;

--[Error] Return only the category with sums of price larger than the average of sum of prices
SELECT category, SUM(price)
FROM film_list
WHERE SUM(price) >
(
   SELECT AVG(sum_price)
   FROM 
   (
       SELECT category, sum(price) AS sum_price
       FROM film_list
       GROUP BY category
   ) AS inner_query
);
```

Any help will be much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Probably you want to use the `HAVING` clause. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-handling.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `group by` and then using `having`

```
SELECT category, SUM(price)
FROM film_list
GROUP BY category
HAVING SUM(price) >
(
   SELECT AVG(sum_price)
   FROM 
   (
       SELECT category, sum(price) AS sum_price
       FROM film_list
       GROUP BY category
   ) AS inner_query
);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is most easily solved using window functions:

```
SELECT c.*
FROM (SELECT category, SUM(price) AS sum_price,
             AVG(SUM(price)) OVER () as avg_total_price
      FROM film_list
      GROUP BY category
     ) c
WHERE sum_price > avg_total_price
```

Comment: it works! just looked up the OVER clause, now I know about window function. Thanks!